# Tool to simulate WPF user control?

Tags: wpf, user-controls

I just wan to know if there are any tools to simulate user control without integrating it to the actual application. I need it just to test the user control's logic and functionality without depending on the whole application itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visual Studio 2008 does that for you,specify your usercontrol path as StartupUri in app.xaml and press <kbd>F5</kbd>, Bingo you can see you control in action :0

Answer (score 2):

If your control is in a control library and you set the control library as the startup project then visual studio will load a User Control Test Container, that is designed just for this purpose, when you start the solution.

You select the control you want to test from a drop down list.  You can then browse to and load any control library assembly.  (I bet this test container could be loaded independently of Visual Studio but I am not sure how.)

Seth

Comment: Although this answer really works but the one above matches my scenario. Thanks.

Comment: Doesn't seem to happen on my Visual Studio 10. When I try to run a debug on the library, it says roughly "Not possible, to debug this library, add an executable project and use from there", which I also don't seem to be able to do...